# wait for asyncio coroutines to finish in specific order

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have a daemon program with a bunch of `asyncio.coroutine`'s that could be summed up to something like this

```
import asyncio
import signal

class Daemon:

    def __init__(self, loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()):
        self.loop = loop
        self.running = False
        self.tasks = {
            'coroutine1': asyncio.ensure_future(self.coroutine1()),
            'coroutine2': asyncio.ensure_future(self.coroutine2()),
        }

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        for task in self.tasks.values():
            task.add_done_callback(self.task_done_callback)
        # gracefuly close everything when SIGINT (could be ^C) is received
        self.loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, self.close)
        self.loop.run_forever()

    def close(self):
        self.running = False
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.tasks['coroutine1'])
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.tasks['coroutine2'])

    def task_done_callback(self, future):
        for task in self.tasks.values():
            if not task.done():
                return
        self.loop.stop()

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def coroutine1(self):
        while self.running:
            print('coroutine1: do stuff')
            yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def coroutine2(self):
        while self.running:
            print('coroutine2: do some other stuff')
            yield from asyncio.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    daemon = Daemon(loop)
    daemon.run()
    loop.close()
```

The daemon is gracefully shut down when a `SIGINT` is received by the program. When this happens the `close()` method is triggered, which is responsible for notifying all tasks running that they should finish their work and stop. This is done simply by setting `running` to `False`. Whenever a task is done, `Daemon.task_done_callback` is triggered. It checks if all tasks are done, if that's the case, then it stops the loop.

The problem here is that the `close()` method is not working. That's because I'm calling `loop.run_until_complete` when the loop is already running (via `run_forever`). This is yielding a `RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')`.

The important thing: **`coroutine1` needs to finish before `coroutine2` because `coroutine1` might have problems doing its stuff if `coroutine2` is not doing its stuff anymore.**

My question here is **how do I make sure `coroutine1` finishes before `coroutine2`?**

Answer (score 0):

this is a way to achieven that. (i remove the `signal` part and just limited the runtime of `coroutine1`).

```
import asyncio

class Daemon:

    def __init__(self, loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()):
        self.loop = loop
        self.tasks = {
            'coroutine1': asyncio.ensure_future(self.coroutine1()),
            'coroutine2': asyncio.ensure_future(self.coroutine2())}

    def run(self):
        for task in self.tasks.values():
            task.add_done_callback(self.task_done_callback)
        self.loop.run_forever()

    def task_done_callback(self, future):
        if all(task.done() for task in self.tasks.values()):
            self.loop.stop()

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def coroutine1(self):
        for _ in range(5):
            print('coroutine1: doing stuff')
            yield from asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print('coroutine1: done!')

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def coroutine2(self):
        while not self.tasks['coroutine1'].done():
            print('coroutine2: doing stuff while coro1 is running')
            yield from asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print('coroutine2: doing stuff after coro1 has ended')
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('coroutine2: done!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    daemon = Daemon(loop)
    daemon.run()
```

the main thing here is to check whether `coroutine1` is still running (your `self.tasks` attribute can be queried for just that).

now to integrate that with `signal` to stop `coroutine1` i'd suggest you register a simple function that sets a flag (e.g. `self.signal_flag`). and then loop inside `coroutine1` with something like `while not self.signal_flag: ...`. these are the changes i would suggest for the complete solution:

```
class Daemon:

    def __init__(self, loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()):
        ...
        self.signal_flag = False

    def run(self):
        ...
        self.loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, self.set_signal_flag)
        self.loop.run_forever()

    def set_signal_flag(self):
        print('caught signal!')
        self.signal_flag = True

    async def coroutine1(self):
        while not self.signal_flag:
            print('coroutine1: doing stuff')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print('coroutine1: done!')
```

also note that there is no need to `close` the loop. in an IDE where the interpreter keeps running this will make things more complicated than they need to be...

starting from python 3.5 you can (and probably should) use this syntax for your coroutines:

```
async def coroutine1(self):
    for _ in range(5):
        print('coroutine1: doing stuff')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
    print('coroutine1: done!')
```